# How to use the Intel C++ Compiler with CMake in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, icc

Visual Studio provides an "Open Folder" workflow for CMake. So far I've been using the default MSVC compiler but I wanted to switch to using the Intel C++ Compiler. To do this, I found [this](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-C-Compiler/Using-Intel-C-compiler-with-Visual-Studio-2017-2019-cmake/m-p/1177277#M36654) post in the Intel forum. However, I'm using Visual Studio 2022. Furthermore, [my Intel C++ compiler](https://registrationcenter-download.intel.com/akdlm/IRC_NAS/94e15cb5-4bcc-4fdd-91cf-0f819a54e42e/w_dpcpp-cpp-compiler_p_2024.0.2.28.exe) is installed under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI`. I assume the updated instructions would now be:

1. Create a `vs2022.cmd` (where though?) with the following contents:

---

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\2024.0\bin" (I don't have `ipsxe-comp-vars.bat` in my installation...) intel64 vs2022
start "VS2022" /B "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
```

2. Run the `vs2022.cmd` file via double-click (in which context?)
3. In Visual Studio, edit your `CMakeSettings.json` config file, add the following (for `Release` configuration):

---

```
{
  "name": "x64-IntelEnv-Release",
  "description": "Start visual studio from Intel C++ compiler environment cmd window",
  "generator": "Ninja",
  "configurationType": "Release",
  "buildRoot": "${workspaceRoot}\\..\\cmake-build\\${name}",
  "installRoot": "${workspaceRoot}\\..\\cmake-install\\${name}",
  "cmakeCommandArgs": "",
  "buildCommandArgs": "-v",
  "ctestCommandArgs": "",
  "inheritEnvironments": [ "msvc_x64_x64" ],
  "variables": [
    {
      "name": "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER",
      "value": "icl.exe",
      "type": "FILEPATH"
    },
    {
      "name": "CMAKE_C_COMPILER",
      "value": "icl.exe",
      "type": "FILEPATH"
    }
  ]
}
```

---

4. Select `x64-IntelEnv-Release` in the `Configurations` dropbox. Build.
   [image]

   [image]

However, the instructions don't seem to be very clear or applicable for my installations (especially the first step). How can I create a build configuration for the Intel Compiler correctly? Ideally, I also don't want to start Visual Studio in the context of the Intel environment command prompt:
[image]